# How Can I Use AWS Lambda To Run Shell Script On A Specific EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Lambda and following some tutorials to learn. But I haven't figured out if I'm able to run some shell script on EC2 instances via AWS Lambda.

I have multiple servers running on AWS EC2 24/7. Within the EC2 instance, I have a script to generate logs, package it and send it to my email. You can assume there's a shell script written in advance for me to trigger.

So far I always use session manager or ssh into each instance to execute the shell script. However, due to the secruity concerns, I'm not going to ssh anymore. As I need to execute the shell script on each server in a particular order, it's painful to open that much session manager and execute each shell scripts one by one manually.

So I wonder if I can get some help from AWS Lambda. My goal is to use AWS Lambda to ssh (or session manager or something else) to get in the EC2 instance to execute the shell script for me. As I have multiple servers, I learned that I can use scripts in AWS Lambda to do this one by one automatically, which would make things easy like triggering a AWS Lambda button to execute shell scripts in each server one by one in a particular order.

Could anyone please provide me some guidence on the AWS Lambda part or some other guidence if there's a better way in AWS to allow me execute shell scripts in multiple EC2 in a particular order automatically. I would appreciate that!

Comment: "Due to the security concerns" - are you disabling ssh?  Is there something else running on the servers that could receive a connection (for example a web server)?

Comment: Can you not run your script at a specified time with something like a cron operation on the box.

Comment: @stdunbar based on our current design, we don't have any web server set up inside. Yes, we disabled the ssh port 22 and we are using aws session manager to go in EC2 boxes for tuning or retrieving logs for now. So I'm looking for a way to use some aws resources like aws lambda to achieve the goal: Runing some shell script inside the EC2 from remote access without using ssh.

Comment: @JamesKn I thought about that case but in my scenario, I'm not running that shell script in a scheduled time. Typically, I just need to run it when I need it. Thus, I'm looking into how to set up a trigger or like a button to let something run the shell scritps for me inside the EC2 instance. Based on my research so far, I found aws lambda could be the potential method to achieve the goal.